# How do you clear a WPF RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

Whenever I do `richtextbox1.Clear()` it says the method doesn't exist. And it's pretty much the only solution I get, everywhere I go.

I've tried looking for a `Text` property, and I've tried to look through the `Document` property as well, but to no avail.

What I am missing? The box needs to be cleared, like you can do with a `textbox.Clear()` call.

Comment: By Document, do you mean you did richtextbox1.Document.Blocks.Clear?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can clear a RichTextBox with `richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Clear();`

Comment: Thank you. What a weird way to do it.

Comment: I'm assuming the developer guy that invented that got fired right?

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding some controls into the richTextBox (e.g. below):

```
LinkLabel link = new LinkLabel();
richTextBox1.Controls.Add(link);
```

you have to use

```
richTextBox1.Controls.Clear();
```

to remove all controls.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this for Windows Forms is to do `richTextBox.ResetText();`

Comment: The questions is for WPF not WinForms.

Answer (score -4):

You could just do `richTextBox.Text = "";`, too.

Comment: the Text Property doesn't exist. When I start writing Text Intellisense gives me: TextInput, TextChanged, PreviewTextInput, AppendText

Comment: The RIchTextBox in Windows.Forms has a [Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx) property. But the WPF [version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) don't.